# Using Regular Expressions to Format FASTA sequences

Tags: python, regex

Fellow Bioinformaticians!

I'm trying to create a python script that will allow me to take in a file that contains non-FASTA formatted sequences and then convert them to FASTA format, and then write them all into a single file that contains all the sequences.

For example: Two non-formatted sequences to a FASTA format...

### non-formatted 1

```
1 tcacatctct acgtactgaa tttaaaggct ttttgtcttt ttctcgtttc tttgcttttc 
61 aatgatgttc aagcgtaacc tcggaaaatg tgtacaaact tgagtacaaa tcgccatatt
```

and

### non-formatted 2

```
1 tcaggagaat gcagatgaca gcagtagcgc accaagtaac cccttttcta acgtcttacg 
61 aagttatggc tcgttaccac attagctata cgacgctctg gcgaagaata aaagatggca
```

and want to convert them to this:

```
>seq1
TCACATCTCTACGTACTGAATTTAAAGGCTTTTTGTCTTTTTCTCGTTTCTTTGCTTTTC
AATGATGTTCAAGCGTAACCTCGGAAAATGTGTACAAACTTGAGTACAAATCGCCATATT
TACCGTTTTTAGCCAAATTCCATGACACAAACCTAGCTGTAGGCCTTGTTCCTACTGGGT
TTTAGCCAAAACTTGCCTATATTTTTTATGCCAAAAATCGAGAAATGATGGTAAGACGTT
CGCGATTATCTCTAATTGTTTGCCGGTTGAGTTGGTTACCGGTTGCTTTCTTGCTGTCC

>seq2
TCAGGAGAATGCAGATGACAGCAGTAGCGCACCAAGTAACCCCTTTTCTAACGTCTTACG
AAGTTATGGCTCGTTACCACATTAGCTATACGACGCTCTGGCGAAGAATAAAAGATGGCA
GCTTGCCGCAACCTCGTATCAACCGAAATACACGAAACAAGCTGTGGCACATTGAAGACT
TGGAGGAGTATGAGAAGAATTAGGAATAGATAGCGTAGCTTAGTTTTTCTGTTGGAGCTT
GGACTAACGCTTTGAAACGCCGGCTTGTGCCAACAATATAGTTAATATGTACACCAACTT
AGGCTAAGATAGCAGCATGGATTTTTTATTGATTGGATGGATAGGTAAGTGACGACTCCT
CAAGAACGGACAACAGGTATTACAAATGCGTCGATAAAAA
```

So far I have this:

```
def cleanandFormat(filename, seqName, seq):
"""
writes out the sequence of an irregular sequence format to a file, while cleaning and       formatting it into the standard form
inputs:
    filename - string of a filename
    seqName - string of sequence description
    seq - string of the sequence
output: clean and standard-formatted data to a file.
"""
#sets the blocklength for the max number of characters in a line
blockLength = 60
with open(filename, 'w') as fh:
    #write out the header and sequence name
    fh.write('>' + seqName + '\n')
    for i in range(0, len(seq), blockLength):
        fh.write(seq[i:i+blockLength].upper() + '\n')


#defines the pattern as any digit and any whitespace
pattern = '\d|\s'
#this will replace the pattern found in the sequence with an empty string
replace = ''

seq = ''
filename = 'seqCleanup2.txt'
with open(filename) as fh:
for line in fh:
    seq += re.sub(pattern, replace, line)
    cleanandFormat('testfasta.txt', 'seqX', seq)
```

Comment: forgot to mention, that I want to stick with regular expressions and that my main issue is figuring out how to recognize a new sequence. I was thinking that I could use REs to find where a number 1 is and go from there.

Comment: So what's the question here? Your method is close to working. We don't fully know the format of the files to help. Is one fasta sequence on a single line for instance? By the way, I would recommend not using += on your string `seq`. Make seq a list and append each sequence to it. Then use something like `'\n'.join(seq)` when you've added everything in. Strings are immutable in Python. This means that every time that you use `seq += `, it creates a new string. With a script like this, it could really slow down if you are working with big files.

Comment: my question is how do i write code so that python KNOWS when a new sequence begins. FASTA file will usually always look like: 1 XXXXXX XXXXX (as above). A new sequence begins when the number '1' is found in front of a sequence

Comment: I suppose that I'm merely looping and writing each DNA sequence to a file, if and when the text begins with a 1

Comment: @Eugene: Then just check as you are going through each line if the first two characters are `"1 "`. If they are, then do your regexp on it. It seems like it should work to me.

Comment: if there are multiple sequences, how do i instruct python to read the sequence UNTIL the next 1 appears?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but here it is in Ruby (not tested), just download ruby, save this in a file and run it:

```
count = 0
while line = gets
  if(line =~ /^1\s[a-z\s]+$/)
    count += 1
    puts
    puts ">seq#{count}"
  end
  if(line =~ /^\d+\s([a-z\s]+)$/)
    puts $1.gsub(/\s/, "").upcase
  end
end
```